# Paperclip problems. Video has been uploaded successfully but when I try to show it it's black

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, paperclip, haml

Don't know why but video is uploaded successfully in the public/system/videos/videos/000/000/:id folder, dunno why videos and 000 doubles but it is nvm. At least I know videos uploaded successfully.

Here is my model:

```
class Video < ActiveRecord::Base
  #mount_uploader :file, VideosUploader
  has_attached_file :video, styles: {
        :medium => {
          :geometry => "640x480",
          :format => 'mp4'
        },
        :thumb => { :geometry => "160x120", :format => 'jpeg', :time => 10}
    }, :processors => [:transcoder]
    validates_attachment_content_type :video, content_type: /\Avideo\/.*\Z/
end
```

Here is my show action:

```
def show
    @video = Video.find(params[:id])
end
```

And here is how i try to print my video:

```
= video_tag @video.video.url
```

All what i get is black screen.

Comment: Can you see the video stored at your uploaded folder?

Comment: Yeah i can. Fixed problem nvm.